# How does an ECS service communicate with a container instance which is running inside a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-ecs, private-subnet, aws-nat-gateway

Today, I was reading about the AWS container orchestration tool which is ECS. I have one question about this. If we place an Ec2 instance on a private subnet, then we require a NAT gateway so that ECS agent can provide info to the ECS service. But how does the ECS service manage the orchestration task if ECS seats on the public network and ec2(container instance) in private.

Comment: So are you asking what happens if you don't have a NAT gateway or instance? Or...? Sorry it's not clear

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary 

Through the NAT gateway, only ECS agent can initiate requests to ECS. Means there is only one way traffic. Then how ECS service create new containers or other orchestration tasks.